# Read vertical text with Google Cloud OCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to read vertical text on the container using GC. It reads perfectly horizontal text, but when it comes to vertical it's a hit or miss.
It seems like API doesn't support any hints like Tesseract.

I've tried several ways to rearrange image to make it pseudo horizontal to trick OCR with no success.

- [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIQkP.jpg)
- [Prediction result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zRN.jpg)

Things I've tried:

- [Sliding window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtTMy.jpg)
- [Duplicating image multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqdnQ.jpg)

When I rearrange letters manually it works like a charm:
[Manual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoWgP.jpg)

Do you have any other ideas on how to prepare image before sending it to OCR?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find semi-working solution using [segment-anything](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything). Hopefully it helps people who ran into the same issue.

Here are my image preprocessing steps:

- Pass image to SamAutomaticMaskGenerator
- Filter out bounding boxes, which don't fit size criteria or overlap
- Crop out bounding box regions with some padding
- Combine cropped regions horizontally and pass it to OCR
- Find correlating boxes from Sam and OCR

These steps lose about 30% of samples, but method helps to cut down on manual labor.

Original image:

[image: vertical]

After image:

[image: horizontal]

Answer (score 0):

A more robust but time-consuming approach is to fine-tune an existing ML model like trOCR on vertical text.

1. Generate a batch of random vertical text using the "[SynthTiger](https://github.com/clovaai/synthtiger)" library.
2. Use this to fine-tune a base trOCR model. This notebook will get 95% there [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/TrOCR/Fine_tune_TrOCR_on_IAM_Handwriting_Database_using_Seq2SeqTrainer.ipynb).
3. Use this model to make predictions on new text

results below after training for 3 epochs
[image]

synthtiger is excellent as it allows you to to add noise, change the background, skew text etc